# Generamba setup failes when using Cocoapods

Tags: swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

Only when using cocoapods(after run pod install), generamba setup failes with the following message when settin path to a .xcodeproj.

```
The path to a .xcodeproj file of the project is 'GrambaSample.xcodeproj'. Do you want to use it? (yes/no) yes
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.2/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:321:in `configure_with_plist': [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa. (RuntimeError)
```

This error won't appear is not using cocoapods.

How can I be able to setup Generamba while using cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue you should update CocoaPods to the latest beta version by executing

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Latest beta version of CocoaPods now using inputFileListPaths and outputFileListPaths.

More info [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.0-beta/) See `.xcfilelist Support`